# Django: changes on css files doesn't load in heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I made a web page using Django and uploaded it in Heroku. I've encountered some minor setback on loading the css, js files in heroku for a while, now I've already fixed them(css/js are now loaded). Now the issue that I have encountered is that when updating my navbar styles in my scss file and compiled without any errors(local) and the changes I've made are showing.

Now I've pushed my changes to my heroku app, it doesn't change at all. I've researched about the problem and took some of the solution but it doesn't work.

In my local:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nydGS.png)

In my prod:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIwqS.png)

Here is my production.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
 )
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

My wsgi.py:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

I've followed this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds

and also Two-scoops-of-Django-1.11 for best practices.

Comment: Open your browser's console, see if you have the right path for your css file.

Comment: Every file paths are correct.

Comment: I've found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem, clearing the cache in my development and prod and pushing the commit fixed my issue. Just in case someone has problems like this that every build(new design, style, etc..).

Try **clearing** the **cache** first then **collectstatic** in your development workstation then **clear cache** in **heroku**, push the new commits. Then collectstatic in heroku if collecstatic is disabled(you can enable automatic collectstatic). Restart heroku, changes will appear.